# opencv imshow causing a memory leak (c++)

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks

I wrote this method (it displays an image):

```
void ImageLoader::displayMyImage()
{
    namedWindow("new_Window1");
    imshow("new_window1", m_image);
    waitKey(2);
}
```

m_image is of **Mat** type.

I also use this destructor:

```
ImageLoader::~ImageLoader()
{
    m_image.release();
}
```

However, Valgrind found tons of memory leaks. It's caused by these two cv functions:
**namedWindow** and **imshow** (because without calling the displayMyImage() there is no any leak).
Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: They are probably false positives, but I don't think you need to call `release()`.

Comment: Are you sure the window is closed before collecting leaks?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It's closed because of the 'waitKey()'.

Comment: If you believe there is a bug in opencv, you can apply for bug report on the following


http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues

Comment: u dont need to explictely call Mat.release(), as already said. You can use [destroyWindow](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=destroywindow#void%20destroyWindow%28const%20string&%20winname%29) to release memory allocated for GUI

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is that you name the named window differently:
**`"new_Window1"` is different from `"new_window1"`**. Second, I tell you I have never used namedWindow, you only need to use imshow to display an image in an image window called `"new_window1"`.

**Remark1:** you don't need to worry about explicitly releasing `m_image`, that is what Mat is for in the first place.

**Remark2:** `waitKey(0)` holds the window forever.

I have seen this question here before, so I think you could search here too for answers.